# How to instantiate a vector of near protocol?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

How to instantiate a vector? What is an id, why it's needed, and what property it should have?

`pub fn new(id: Vec<u8>) -> Self`
Create new vector with zero elements. Use id as a unique identifier on the trie.
https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Vector.html

It gives error:

```
let id = account_id.into_bytes();
let mut products_list = Vector::new(id);
   |             -----------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted cannot infer the type of type parameter `T` in the generic `Vector<T>` type. You are going to have to provide a type annotation for `products_list`, so that the compiler knows the complete type (see [data types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html)).

Comment: And just to be precise, here's an example: 
`let mut products_list: Vector<String> = Vector::new(b"something".to_vec());` and
`products_list.push(&"aloha".to_string());`